# how to add image to tooltip using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, tooltip

I am using visual studio 2012 (win forms)

i would like to add clarification images with titles for my text boxes & labels, i tried the tool tip as text only, it works great, but i would like to add images to them to be like this example clarified here: 
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGuBIqVUc5c&feature=youtu.be)

i searched the topics here, but the only one i found was with c#, which iam not familiar with, so any help for using it with vb.net will be great.
knowing that the only available property in properties window is "tooltip for tooltip 1" nothing regarding tooltip image.

thanks a lot..,

Comment: You can't do this using the WinForms tooltip control. Just create a form with the appropriate text and images on and show it when the mouse hover event fires?

Comment: @MattWilko does this mean i have to make form for each label & text in my application ?

Comment: No just create a generic form that contains an images and text and expose these as properties that you can set before showing it

Comment: @MattWilko sorry, but iam just a beginner here & i don't know how to implement this idea, any guided help will be much appreciated., thanks alot

Comment: @MattWilko any guided help here please

Answer (score 0):

you could use the Web Controls Image control [System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image],just set the tool-tip by setting the ToolTip property for this control.

Comment: i need more clarification please, how to add the title separately & how to choose the image as a resource file, i want it to be like the same one here: (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iGuBIqVUc5c&feature=youtu.be). also the tool tip property allow me to add text only !

Comment: this should help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98967/A-ToolTip-with-Title-Multiline-Contents-and-Image

Comment: thanks for the link & these rich info, but the thing here is that all i have in my property window regarding tooltip is "tooltip on tooltip 1", there is nothing for tooltip image as clarified in the link

Comment: OwnerDraw property, if true, the tooltip's surface will be drawn by your code, Popup and Draw events will be raised, otherwise, the tooltip surface will be drawn itself.
OwnerDrawBackground property, if true, both background and surface of the tooltip will be drawn by your code, Popup, DrawBackground, and Draw events will be raised, otherwise, the tooltip background will be drawn itself.

Comment: ., the only available property in properties window is "OwnerDraw" & i made it true, there is nothing regarding "OwnerDrawBackground property", & please if you can clarify the code to use the tool tip, when mouse hover above any label (for example). thanks for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty hack that uses images stored as resources in the project file

```vb
Public Class ImageTip
    Inherits ToolTip

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.OwnerDraw = True 'Must be set otherwise will not draw the image properly
        Me.IsBalloon = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ImageTip_Draw(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DrawToolTipEventArgs) _
                Handles Me.Draw
        'Draws the image in the tooltip popup by reading the tooltip
        'text on the control that you want to have a popup for
         e.Graphics.DrawImage(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(e.ToolTipText), 0, 0)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ImageTip_Popup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PopupEventArgs) _
                Handles Me.Popup
        'Creates the popup and sets its dimensions from the resource name
        Dim Image As Image
        Dim ToolText As String

        ToolText = Me.GetToolTip(e.AssociatedControl)
        If ToolText <> "" Then
            Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(ToolText)
            If Image IsNot Nothing Then
                e.ToolTipSize = New Size(Image.Width, Image.Height)
            Else
                e.Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```